# Can not build the project after upgrading to mule version 3.8.4 to 3.7.4

Tags: maven, mule, version, anypoint-studio

Previously I was building the project with the mule version 3.7.4. now, as mule version 3.8.4 is the latest one, so planned to build with this latest version. So,
from Anypoint Studio I have downloaded the latest version.
Then I updated my POM file with the 3.8.4 version. But it seems that with the same jars its not  able to build the project.
Its gives error as

---

### Failed to execute goal on project sho-pointofsales: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sho:sho-pointofsales:mule:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-tracking-ee:jar:3.8.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-tracking-ee:jar:3.8.4: Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-tracking-ee:pom:3.8.4 from/to mule-ee-releases (https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Although I placed this jar inside my local REPO. Don't know what is wrong I am doing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.` you are not allowed to access this repository...cause there are some files which are missing...

Comment: U said files are missing, means from where? from my local REPO or Central Repo. because in my local .m2/repo folder files are present.

Comment: As the error messsage states from the `https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee` repository... The artifact which can't be requested is: `com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-tracking-ee:pom:3.8.4`...

Comment: So, what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following stuff:
a. You can either comment the enterprise repository in the pom.xml file.
b. Check if the enterprise repository is accessible from your browser.
c. verfiy username and password.

Answer (score 3):

It exists: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/com/mulesoft/muleesb/modules/mule-module-tracking-ee/

check your username and password in your settings.xml or pom etc for that repo.

But it's part of the platform anyway and doesn't need to be explicit in your pom. So just remove it from the pom or set it the scope to 'provided' on the dependency