# mulesoft Dependencies Error

Tags: java, mule

I am a fresher currently working on mulesoft,I am facing dependency problems but I cross checked all dependencies are available in my pom file.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project panduit-sapi-01: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.panduit:panduit-sapi-01:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.anypoint:api-gateway-client:jar:3.8.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.anypoint:api-gateway-client:jar:3.8.3: Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.anypoint:api-gateway-extensions:pom:3.8.3 from/to mule-ee-releases (https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: Check the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627366/can-not-build-the-project-after-upgrading-to-mule-version-3-8-4-to-3-7-4/43633297#43633297

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an account on Maven Nexus which consist of enterprise repositories. Account wii be provided upon purchasing the license. When you got your credentials, add it to setting.xml of the maven.

See reference below on how to add the credentials,

https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/_adding_credentials_to_your_maven_settings.html

For you to proceed, remove the enterprise repositories, everything should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in your pom.

```
<repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try setting the preferences for Installed JREs to 1.8 JDK. It should fix the issues.

Comment: did you try doing this?

Comment: If you watch the error log closely,it  shows-

"Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.anypoint:api-gateway-extensions:pom:3.8.3 from/to mule-ee-releases (https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/): 
Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]"

Which suggest its related to repo access as already pointed in accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

all *-ee.jar dependencies are available with license, Please try to purchase license and include the license key in settings xml.